# JMeter - Multi User login to a site, each user picks up one number randomly and send HTTP request

Tags: jmeter, performance

I have requirement given below.

- 100 different users (Defined in CSV file) - Login to a site
  sequentially.
- Simultaneously logged in users start to a pick a Number
  from a CSV file (Totallu 10,000 numbers in CSV) and sending HTTP request.
- This should repeat till 10,000 numbers used in sending HTTP request logged in by the 100 users.

Currently I am able to do with 100 users, logging in and picking 100 numbers sequentially. This is easy task.

Comment: Welcome. It is unclear to me what you are asking here? You have it working you state, so what is your problem?

Comment: Hi Actually, I am trying to create a JMeter script which does all the above steps.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand the question I think the answer is

pseudo code:

```
number_from_csv = 1
for each of 100 groups (group)
  for each of 100 users (user)
    get_csv_value(number_from_csv) # however u do this
    increment number_from_csv
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the comment. I got other option. I am creating a separate thread group for each user and assigning a CSV contains some set of numbers and sending in HTTP request these numbers. Also, for sending multiple HTTP requests, I am using record controller.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the above-mentioned requirement, you can use the following steps in JMeter:

1. Add a CSV Data Set Config element to read the 10,000 numbers from the CSV file.
2. Add a Thread Group element to simulate the 100 users logging in sequentially to the site.
3. Inside the Thread Group, add a Loop Controller element to repeat the login process till 10,000 numbers are used.
4. Add a HTTP Request element to perform the login action. You can use the CSV Data Set Config element to pass the username and password for each user.
5. After successful login, add a Random Controller element to randomly select a number from the CSV file.
6. Add another HTTP Request element to send the HTTP request with the selected number.
7. Repeat steps 5 and 6 till all 10,000 numbers are used.

You can also use the CSV Data Set Config element to pass the selected number to the HTTP request.

You can refer to the following resources for more information:

- JMeter User Manual: https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/
- JMeter CSV Data Set Config: https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config
- JMeter Random Controller: https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Random_Controller